# Android Volley does not seem to post HTTP parameters

Tags: android, android-volley

I've seen a few of these questions on StackOverflow but I can't seem to work out why this code is not working for me.

```
public void postMethod(final String msg) {

    String url = "http://192.168.1.30/endpoint";

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, 
        new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            // Handle response...
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // Handle error...
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("msg", msg);

            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(sr);
}
```

I'm trying to make a POST to my server which is running a python flask application. If I use a program to make HTTP Post requests my server application works fine. It will also work fine if I use an AsyncTask and do what Volley is trying to do for me.

From all of the examples I have seen this code should work fine but my flask server never receives any of the POST parameters. Any ideas what might be happening?

**EDIT**

Server Code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/endpoint', methods=['POST'])
def echo_msg():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            msg = request.form['msg']
            return msg

        except KeyError, e:
            # A required parameter is missing.
            abort(400)
```

Comment: what is the web page code??

Comment: @MDMalik I updated the question with my server code.

Answer (score 7):

You need to override getBodyContentType() and return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";

```
StringRequest jsonObjRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            getResources().getString(R.string.base_url),
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    MyFunctions.toastShort(LoginActivity.this, response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d("volley", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    MyFunctions.croutonAlert(LoginActivity.this,
                            MyFunctions.parseVolleyError(error));
                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }) {

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("username", etUname.getText().toString().trim());
            params.put("password", etPass.getText().toString().trim());
            return params;
        }

    };

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjRequest);
```

Comment: I removed the getHeaders overriding too, because a was adding a **Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded** as header and I keeped the **getBodyContentType** and **getParams** overriding

Comment: What about sending a JSONArray as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the body to pass your parameters, as it's done in `JsonObjectRequest`.

In `JsonObjectRequest` you can set a JSONObject as the body of the request. I'd suggest either switching you request type to this type, or overriding the `getBody()` method of your `StringRequest` similarly to the way it's done in `JsonRequest` (line 93).

Comment: I think i would need that. Could you add some code please?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you've solved the problem. I faced a similar issue while implementing a code similar to yours.
The code below actually worked for me. Thanks

```
public void postMethod(final String msg) {

String url = "http://192.168.1.30/endpoint";

Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("msg", msg);

RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new JSONObject (params),
    new Response.Listener<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Handle response...
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // Handle error...
    }
}){
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        return params;
    }
};
queue.add(sr);
```

}

Hope this helps anyone who ever faces such a problem. Thank you.

Comment: There's no constructor in StringRequest like the one you've used in your code. Have you used a custom Request and named it like the one in the volley package?

Answer (score 0):

You can use encoded form application/x-www-form-urlencoded only this method

```
@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
}
```