# Android volley post methode parameter missing

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using android volley library to post data to back-end service. But I can't send any parameter with my request. I have done each and everything mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22072066/android-volley-does-not-seem-to-post-http-parameters) . But none works for me. The post method that I am using is:

```
 public static void post()
{

    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";

    String url = "http://myUrl";


    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, obj,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("TAG", response.toString());

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("TAG", "Error: " + error.getMessage());

        }
    }) {

        /**
         * Passing some request headers
         * */
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();

            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        }



        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("key", "value");


            return params;
        }
    };
// Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);


}
```

Always the response is "parameter missing".
How could i resolve this issue?

Comment: The link that you provide is about StringRequest... JsonObjectRequest is not using getParams.

Comment: so can u help me with jsonobject request? the below answer is not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `JSONObjectRequest`, you can try this.

```
    String url = "http://myurl";
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("key", value);

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, new JSONObject(params),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                    try {
                        success = jsonObject.getInt("success");
                        message = jsonObject.getString("message");

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    Activity activity = getActivity();
                    if (volleyError instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                        String errormsg = "Check your internet connection";
                        Toast.makeText(activity, errormsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

The codes are more likely the same as yours. Check on the lines where I put the data to be posted. I'm very sure this would work!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are approaching the request as though you were making a `stringRequest`.  The link you reference is talking specifically about making a `stringRequest`.

`jsonObjectRequest` actually lets you put the json object into the constructor itself, instead of using the override method `getParams()` like so:

```
    String url = "some_url";
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put(Constants.LOGIN_EMAIL_ID, email);
        jsonObject.put(Constants.LOGIN_PASSWORD, password);
    }catch(JSONException e){
        Log.d("JSON error", e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest =  new JsonObjectRequest(url, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("RESPONSE", response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            if(error.getMessage()!=null){
                Log.d("RESPONSE", error.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });


    VolleySingleton.getInstance(activity).getRequestQueue().add(jsObjRequest);
```

Comment: I have edited my answer for a more full code example.  I have tested this and it works.  The last answer had syntax errors, but the concept is correct.  I would recommend testing your api with something like Postman, to see if it will handle test calls correctly if you are still getting errors using the above code

Comment: the thing was i was needed a string request instead of json request.