# Error in passing JSON object response to TextView for Testing purposes

Tags: java, php, android, postman, jsonobjectrequest

I saw the other posts but its no use and I am still getting error why is it that I keep getting this error. I have been trying to pass my JSONObject response to my TextView to check if it really contains an object before I try and pass it to some tables. and it seems based on the error I am getting no value for Branches? why? I think my JSON Obj matches with my postman result.

Here is my error:

```
2019-11-10 09:21:51.577 14371-14371/com.example.sample1myapp W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for Branches
2019-11-10 09:21:51.577 14371-14371/com.example.sample1myapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:399)
2019-11-10 09:21:51.577 14371-14371/com.example.sample1myapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:594)
2019-11-10 09:21:51.577 14371-14371/com.example.sample1myapp W/System.err:     at com.example.sample1myapp.main.Functions.dash_branch.branch$1.onResponse(branch.java:100)
2019-11-10 09:21:51.577 14371-14371/com.example.sample1myapp W/System.err:     at com.example.sample1myapp.main.Functions.dash_branch.branch$1.onResponse(branch.java:96)
2019-11-10 09:21:51.577 14371-14371/com.example.sample1myapp W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:90)
2019-11-10 09:21:51.578 14371-14371/com.example.sample1myapp W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
2019-11-10 09:21:51.578 14371-14371/com.example.sample1myapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
2019-11-10 09:21:51.578 14371-14371/com.example.sample1myapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
2019-11-10 09:21:51.578 14371-14371/com.example.sample1myapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
2019-11-10 09:21:51.578 14371-14371/com.example.sample1myapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
2019-11-10 09:21:51.578 14371-14371/com.example.sample1myapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2019-11-10 09:21:51.578 14371-14371/com.example.sample1myapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
2019-11-10 09:21:51.578 14371-14371/com.example.sample1myapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
2019-11-10 09:21:51.578 14371-14371/com.example.sample1myapp E/response: {"error":true,"message":"Error Occured 102"}
```

Main code for this problem:

```
public class branch extends AppCompatActivity {

    //getting the current sysID use in protected params
    private static final String KEY_SYS_ID = "sys_id";
    private int sys_Id = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUserid();

    //View Branch
    private static final String KEY_VB_ID = "branchid";
    private static final String KEY_VB_USER = "username";
    private static final String KEY_VB_PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String KEY_VB_NAME = "branchname";
    private static final String KEY_VB_SYSID = "sys_id";
    private static final String KEY_VB_CREATED = "created";
    private static final String KEY_VB_UT = "user_type";

    private String url = "http://192.168.1.2/sample1/v1/viewBranches.php";

    private TextView testdata;
    private NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_branch);
        if (!SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()) {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, login.class));
            return;
        }

        testdata = findViewById(R.id.testdatatv);
        nestedScrollView = findViewById(R.id.nested);

    }

    public void retrieve() {
         JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("Branches");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject branch = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                int viewBranchID = branch.getInt(KEY_VB_ID);
                                String viewBranchUser = branch.getString(KEY_VB_USER);
                                String viewBranchPassword = branch.getString(KEY_VB_PASSWORD);
                                String viewBranchName = branch.getString(KEY_VB_NAME);
                                int viewBranchSYSID = branch.getInt(KEY_VB_SYSID);
                                int viewBranchCreated = branch.getInt(KEY_VB_CREATED);
                                String viewBranchUT = branch.getString(KEY_VB_UT);

                                testdata.append(
                                        String.valueOf(viewBranchID)+""+
                                                viewBranchUser+""+
                                                viewBranchPassword+""+
                                                viewBranchName+""+
                                                String.valueOf(viewBranchSYSID)+""+
                                                String.valueOf(viewBranchCreated)+""+
                                                viewBranchUT+"\n\n");
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e("response", "" + response);
                        }
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("response", "" + error);

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put(KEY_SYS_ID, String.valueOf(sys_Id));
                return params;
            }

        };
        RequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    /**
     * Show populated Table
     */
    public void onTableshow(View view){
        //tableView = (TableView<String[]>) findViewById(R.id.tableView);
        //new bTSQLClient(branch.this).retrieve(tableView);
        retrieve();
    }

}
```

XML class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".main.Functions.dash_branch.branch">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
            android:onClick="onBack"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:text="Back"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.008"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"></Button>

        <Button
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnAdd"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onTableshow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show">
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30sp"
            android:onClick="onAddBranch"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:text="+"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.008"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"></Button>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutviewbranch"
        android:padding="8sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nested"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/testdatatv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000">
            </TextView>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

PHP code

```
<?php
require_once '../DbOperations.php';

$response = array();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    if(isset($_POST['sys_id'])){
        $db = new DbOperations();

        if($db->select($_POST['sys_id'])){
            $user = $db->getBranchDataByID($_POST['sys_id']);
            $response['Branches'] = $user;

        }else{
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = "Error Occured 101";
        }

    }else{
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = "Error Occured 102";
    }
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

The related codes on db_Operation that were used on the above code

```
         public function select($sys_id){
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT branchid FROM branch_Data WHERE sys_id = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $sys_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            return $stmt->num_rows > 0;
        }
        //System Data
          public function getBranchDataByID($sys_id){
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM branch_Data WHERE sys_id = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("i",$sys_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                $branchinfo[]=$data;
            }
            return $branchinfo;
        }
```

POSTMAN OUTPUT

```
{
    "Branches": [
        {
            "branchid": 12,
            "username": "king",
            "password": "202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70",
            "branchname": "123branch",
            "sys_id": 8,
            "created": "2019-10-28 20:45:08",
            "user_type": "Branch"
        },
        {
            "branchid": 13,
            "username": "makoy",
            "password": "bda639c314e39023789c37d7a07469f9",
            "branchname": "makoy",
            "sys_id": 8,
            "created": "2019-10-28 20:50:41",
            "user_type": "Branch"
        },
        {
            "branchid": 14,
            "username": "foodbranch",
            "password": "202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70",
            "branchname": "foodbranch",
            "sys_id": 8,
            "created": "2019-10-28 22:01:59",
            "user_type": "Branch"
        },
        {
            "branchid": 15,
            "username": "081nao397",
            "password": "7815696ecbf1c96e6894b779456d330e",
            "branchname": "testingbranchname",
            "sys_id": 8,
            "created": "2019-11-08 08:21:01",
            "user_type": "Branch"
        },
        {
            "branchid": 16,
            "username": "testing101",
            "password": "7815696ecbf1c96e6894b779456d330e",
            "branchname": "rest",
            "sys_id": 8,
            "created": "2019-11-08 08:28:55",
            "user_type": "Branch"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am correct, right? I have one JSON Object, inside of JSON Object there is one array which is `Branches` which has 5 objects separated with commas? That means I am doing my JSON Object request correct right?

Here is the PostMan screen which sends the request.

[image]

Comment: I could not find any error about your JSON parser. Are you sure that the JSON String that you posted is the one that you are getting from the php backend?

Comment: yeah i think so sir

Comment: ah and now the error changed and i think before i posted this code i accidentally put the Method on java to GET then i turned it back to POST to match my php and this new error came up ! il update the error code

Comment: Looks like the response that you are getting is the following - `{"error":true,"message":"Error Occured 102"}`. You do not have the `Branches` information here which is why you are getting the error. Please check if you are passing the parameters to the POST request correctly and the server-side is returning appropriate data based on a valid request.

Comment: yeah but i checked the postman and used post there with the sys_id parameter and it gets the correct result which is the postman result that i posted above

Comment: wait, is this correct? what i did is in order to send the sys_id to my php code, i put it in my get params which is the params.put(KEY_SYS_ID, String.valueOf(sys_Id));

Comment: Can you please post the screenshot of how you are sending the parameter using PostMan?

Comment: sure sir here, https://snipboard.io/cluBCG.jpg

Comment: I think you are missing the content type setup in your request. I have added an answer mentioning this. Let me know if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I think you might go for a `StringRequest` instead of a `JsonObjectRequest` as follows.

```
StringRequest jsonObjReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
        new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());

                    // Parse your JSON data here. 

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                }
            }
        }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        System.out.println("error:: " + error.toString());
    }
})

{
    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put(KEY_SYS_ID, String.valueOf(sys_Id));
        return params;
    }
};
```

**OLD:**

The `setContentType` is missing and passing `String` parameter instead of `Integer`.

```
public void retrieve() {

     JSONObject param = new JSONObject();

     try {
        param.put("sys_id", sys_Id);
     } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }

     // Pass the param while creating the request
     JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Constants.viewbranches_url, param,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("Branches");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject branch = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            int viewBranchID = branch.getInt(KEY_VB_ID);
                            String viewBranchUser = branch.getString(KEY_VB_USER);
                            String viewBranchPassword = branch.getString(KEY_VB_PASSWORD);
                            String viewBranchName = branch.getString(KEY_VB_NAME);
                            int viewBranchSYSID = branch.getInt(KEY_VB_SYSID);
                            int viewBranchCreated = branch.getInt(KEY_VB_CREATED);
                            String viewBranchUT = branch.getString(KEY_VB_UT);

                            testdata.append(
                                    String.valueOf(viewBranchID)+""+
                                            viewBranchUser+""+
                                            viewBranchPassword+""+
                                            viewBranchName+""+
                                            String.valueOf(viewBranchSYSID)+""+
                                            String.valueOf(viewBranchCreated)+""+
                                            viewBranchUT+"\n\n");
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("response", "" + response);
                    }
                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("response", "" + error);

        }
    }) {

        // Set the content type here
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
        }

    };
    RequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Comment: is my getParams sir is correct? with the getParams i can send the current sys_id from the sharedpreferences and send it to php code to get all content related to that sys_id?

Comment: I think you are right. You are passing the param as `String`, where it should be passed as an `Integer`. I have updated my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: aw ty sir for the help very much appreciated it! but  i still get the same error sir

Comment: What is your URL?

Comment: wait sir il add my Constant class so u can see my URL but im sure that im passing the correct url sir

Comment: Yes, the URL looks correct. I am not sure what is happening here.

Comment: Can you please see the update? I have added an update to my answer.

Comment: You might also look into the answers here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22072066/android-volley-does-not-seem-to-post-http-parameters

Comment: okay sir but if i put String request i wont be able to get The array of the object right sir?

Comment: You can still get the `JsonObject` in the `onResponse`.

Comment: ah right tyvm sir! i finaly got the correct response on my logcat! hmm but why is it that it wont show on my textview sir?

Comment: anyway finaly! now i know that im getting the correct response! tyvm for the help sir

Comment: Glad to know that your problem is solved! Happy to help you!